# Getting data from another component on created() VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am struggling with toggling between 2 locations (Scotland and Delaware).

I can easily pass and change content of each page when a button is clicked using a bus.

```
bus.$emit("contentChange", mainLocation);
```

Issue is when the page loads it's blank because the button in the header has not been clicked.

How can I pass mainLocation variable from my header component to each page before the content is shown?

By default the mainLocation should be 'Delaware'.

My header component is used within App.vue to make it available on every page.

```
 <div id="app">
    <Header />
    <router-view />
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: So do you have a parent child communication? Could you provide more code please?

Comment: There is no parent communication, I don't think, as the header component is used within App.vue to make it available on every page.

Comment: Have a data property in header set to `Delaware` and then change the data property using bus?

Answer (score 0):

There a few way you can handle this

1. You could `emit` an event at startup. In your case running `bus.$emit("contentChange", "Delaware");` But you could have timing issues, if you fire the event, but the listening components aren't initialised then you'll miss it.
2. A more robust method would be to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). You'll set up your store and trigger a mutation at the start that sets the default location. After that any component can use the state to figure out what is the current selected location.